# Relationship between import, require and /// <reference

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript. Here's a snippet:

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts" />
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    filename = process.argv[2];
```

Why is the `///` line required in this case? I thought that it would only be required with an import.

On the other hand, here's another snippet:

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import fs = require('fs');
import should = require('should');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
```

In this case, 'csv-parse' does not have a tsd file installed (in typings/) nor listed in tsd.json and yet that line does not give an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the /// line required in this case?

Don't recomment using `reference` comments anymore. These were *before* there was something like `tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md These were to tell the IDE which other files need to be a part of the compilation context.

> 'csv-parse' does not have a tsd file installed (in typings/) nor listed in tsd.json and yet that line does not give an error?

This is because you are using `var/require` in `var parse = require('csv-parse');` instead of `import/require`.

If you use `import/require` *you will get an error*. `require` is a function defined in `node.d.ts` which means `var/require` is allowed but not *typechecked* the same way as `import/require`.

Comment: Thanks very helpful. Is import then a 'reserved word' in Typescript, vs. just a function?

Comment: Yes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import 
< typescript supports this syntax as well as the `import/require` that you are seeing

Comment: Ok I did some more digging and am still a tiny bit confused. Looks like "require" is indeed a function defined by node (and maybe elsewhere) and it does kind of what an include does in C. And then it looks like import is in fact a new reserved word built into ECMA 2015 presumably to standardize and maybe improve on the require function's behavior which came from outside ECMA-land. Reasonable summary?